# How to start a project? (Not literally)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Just looking for a basic answer as to where to start my project.  First off, I am fairly new to java and all other languages so I'm no pro.  I am just looking for an answer from anyone more knowledged than myself as to a sort of template for new projects.

I try and make new projects by myself to test what I have learned so far but often find myself extremely overwhelmed at the start of a project because I don't know where to start!  I have so many keywords in my mind that I should be using to accomplish the goal of my project but can never figure out where to start wring the code!

What I am looking for is someone to just help me understand where I should/ how I should start a project?

Thanks in advance!

Alex Gunther

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone down rated this question so I felt obliged to answer as its not a dumb question.  When your first learning a language its a good idea to start out with simple executable and try and test what you know about the language.  With Javascript that's the console in your browser, with Java that's the Main Method.  Your initial few projects will all just be one class with a Main method, as your code starts to grow it will force you to learn how to refactor and create good classes and modularity.  I also recommending take a basic beginner course on a sight such as Udemy.com as it will teach about necessary libraries and frameworks to creating meaningful code.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to respond to my question!  I cannot see that someone downvoted it but I genuinely meant it as a legitimate question :/  I am already enrolled in a couple courses on Udemy including Tim Buchakas Java course which has turned out to be amazing so far.  I am about 15% through the course but I only ask this question now because I am finding it hard to start my own projects of sorts.

Comment: Yeah I up voted it to put it back to zero

Comment: :'( thank you for being a good guy!

Answer (score 1):

A project should always be started in your head, then if your serious, on paper. thinking out everything you will need, planning classes and variables and coming up with some pseudo-code (writing out what you think the code you will need looks like) are always the first steps.

if you are looking for some sample projects there are plenty of tutorial sites, that will run you through making different stuff step by step. this is a good place to start.

if your just looking to test your skills with `Java` check out [CodingBat](https://codingbat.com/java)

but if you want a good place to start coding altogether, Download Unity3d, it supports `c#` and `JavaScript` (not to be confused with `Java`)

the reason i recommend unity3d is they have fully documented code for almost everything on their site, and lots of good video tutorials as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a great question. I would upvote if I could. I've felt the same when I was just starting out.

I usually make a rough plan of what I need on paper. What classes are going to serve what purpose and how do I want to structure them?

I then start to create the packages I use to structure and then the main classes. (My main() always just contains a call to a different funtion/object because I don't like static) From there I just build forward. The logic, then the interface and so on. I usually also structure the logic into different aspects.

Also you might want to make a priority list.

[Here is my latest GitHub repo](https://github.com/DapfiDuck/KarmaGrapher/tree/master/KarmaGrapher/src). This is just a snapshot of what my structure looks like at the moment.

Comment: hey I really appreciate your comment! This is exactly the sort of advice I was looking for! It seems a few people say to start in your head and on paper so maybe that's what I'm missing! Just visualizing it before I just jump in!

Comment: @AlexGunther You might want to upvote this Answer ( not comment ) as a way of saying thanks to the person who took the time to write it

Comment: Thanks for suggesting it, I did but the problem is I have less than 15 reputation so it doesn't show up yet... 

Comment: @Alex Gunther  No Problem :)

Answer (score 0):

if you use ECLIPSE:

FILE >> PROJECT >> JAVA PROJECT and give name to project >> finish

if you use NETBEANS:

FILE >> NEW PROJECT >> JAVA >> JAVA APPLICATION and give name to project >> finish

If you want more go to:

http://help.eclipse.org/photon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-3.htm

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ubwRUfvXJpE

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K3twuFyPwkg

if you want some video tutorials completely free search on youtube "JAVA video tutorial"

Comment: Hey thanks for commenting! I didn't mean literally how to start a new project, I just meant how to go about starting a new project and how to lay one out! Have a good day!

Comment: Sorry if I was wrong to understand.